# How do I disable only certain/specific warnings in my XML files?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, warnings

I am using Eclipse. I want to disable a certain warning in my XML and leave all of the other warnings alone.  Because some of my strings are consists of many sub parts, example:

```
1. blah  blah blah blah
   a) blah blah blah
   b) blah blah blah
  c) blah blah blah
```

The issue is because I tend use '(c)', it generates a warning to use the copyright attribute, ©. I did not mean copyright, I mean (c). How do I turn just this specific warning off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying opening from eclipse the following and see if it helps?

Window -->preferences --> android -->> Lint Error Checking

In the search box type in internationalization

Highlight HardcodedText and you can change its severity to something like "ignore".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences --> Android --> Lint Error Checking.  There are plenty of options in there to customize your errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable those sorts of warnings on a case-by-case basis, an Eclipse quick-fix (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) for the warning will add an appropriate `tools:ignore` attribute to the element.